# How to trap keystrokes in Windows Forms (C ++)?

Tags: c++, winforms, webbrowser-control

The Form has a DataGridView (there is displayed a single line) and WebBrowser.

The Form's Event keyDown has a handler that is activated by pressing the `F2`, which writes the word in a particular cell. The same function is bound to the `DataGridView`.

```
private: System::Void CSV_WViewForm_KeyDown(
    System::Object^  sender,
    System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e)
    {
        if (e->KeyCode == Keys::F2)
            /*Do something*/;           
    }
```

It is necessary to press `F2` to always worked, and once (the first time). For this I used the property `KeyPreview = false`; (I tried a true - not worked) and the next code:

```
protected:
    virtual bool ProcessCmdKey(Message% msg, Keys keyData) override
    {
        if (keyData == Keys::F2)
        {
            this->dataGridView1->Focus();
            return Form::ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData);
        }
        return Form::ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData);
    }
```

But when the Focus is in WebBrowser, `F2` does not always work (sometimes it is necessary to press F2 twice). How to beat it?

The project is in `Visual Studio 2015 (C++)`

Comment: If it had teeth then it would have bit you.  Focus() is useless, move the /*Do something*/ code into ProcessCmdKey().

Comment: Greats! It works. Thank you